# QSerialPort.write() only works on MacOs if QThread::sleep() is called

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, serial-port

I have noticed some very strange behavior in QSerialPort on QT 5.7 between Windows7 and MacOs Sierra.  On my particular setup, I'm communicating with a custom serial device.  I have code that works on Windows 7 just fine, but it requires modification to work properly on MacOs.  I've spent 20 or so hours fiddling around with the code, and I've found what works, but in searching the documentation, I have no idea *why* it works.

**Here's the code that works just fine on Windows7**

```
QByteArray line = FileToWriteOut.readLine();
while (!line.isEmpty())
{
   //QThread::msleep(2);    //Apparently MacOs won't continuously write to the port without this?
   qint64 nwrite = MyQSerialPort->write(line);
   line = FileToWriteOut.readLine();
}
```

**On MacOS (In this case -- the version is Sierra,)** 
I run into different behavior.  After some small number of writes (on the order of 13 writes of 44 characters each,) writing stops.  No signals are thrown, and upon probing futher, I find that the serial port buffer fills up, and a QSerialPort::ResourceError is set.

**I've tried the following things:**

- waitForBytesWritten(-1) in the loop.  13 or so successful writes, then freezes.
- bytesWritten signal connected to a method to send more data instead of a loop.  Again, 13 or so successful writes, then freezes.
- QThread::msleep() after the write.  Intermittently works, or freezes.
- QThread::msleep() before the write. Seems to work 100% of the time.
- QSerialPort::flush() after a write.  Returns false, no bytes get written.

So.  I feel like I've solved my implementation problem, but I don't understand why this fixes the behavior on mac.  I've dug into the documentation, with no mention of sleeping threads to get the write to work.  it seems the general consensus is that using waitForBytesWritten(-1) is the proper way to go, yet this doesn't seem to work in this case.

Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: _ I find that the serial port buffer fills up_ -- so why not call bool `QSerialPort::flush()` then?

Comment: Thought I had that in the list of things that I tried.  Good find, I added it to the list.  I did try this, same story as the other attempts, other than sleeping the thread in the loop before another write.